# How to create VirtualBox image template with bridged network connection

Tags: virtualbox

I need to create VirtualBox image with bridged network connection. It should start on another machine without any questions or warnings with bridged connection available as eth0.

.vbox configuration has BridgedInterface element, but it contains interface name and issues a warning when opening on another machine:

```
<Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027111111" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <DisabledModes>
        <NAT>
          <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
          <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        </NAT>
      </DisabledModes>
      <BridgedInterface name="en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"/>
    </Adapter>
```

I can do it with VmWare (no warnings when starting image with bridged connection)

Answer (score 0):

While I can't configure bridged connection, I can configure NAT and port forwarding to achieve the same (seamless) installation experience. Configuration with NAT port forward:

```
<Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027111111" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
      <NAT>
        <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
        <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
        <Forwarding name="Tomcat" proto="1" hostport="8443" guestport="8443"/>
      </NAT>
</Adapter>
```